# SIGTERM not getting trappped on shutdown

Tags: python, signals

i am trying to detect system shutdown in python script where i need to stop a thread gracefully
it only traps it when i do kill -15 pid, but when i do shutdown -P or shutdown -r it does not trap the signal

```
import time
import threading
import signal


class Job(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.shutdown_flag = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.shutdown_flag.is_set():
            time.sleep(0.5)

        f = open('threads.log', 'a')
        f.write('%s Thread #%s stopped\n' % self.ident)
        f.close()


class ServiceExit(Exception):
    pass


def service_shutdown(signum, frame):
    print('Caught signal %d' % signum)
    raise ServiceExit


def main():

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, service_shutdown)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, service_shutdown)

    try:
        j1 = Job()
        j2 = Job()
        j1.start()
        j2.start()

        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)

    except ServiceExit:
        j1.shutdown_flag.set()
        j2.shutdown_flag.set()
        j1.join()
        j2.join()

    print('Exiting main program')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it does not trap the signal but that the signal is not sent at that time. You have to configure systemd to do that for Your program.

Comment: sorry do you mean not sent to the threads? because i can trap and log SIGTERM in a non-thread function on shutdown but wondering why it is not working on a thread. could not find anything on how to configure systemd, all i found is that it is already configured to send SIGTERM by default